# python pointer to an integer

Tags: python, pointers

I was wondering if there is any way to recreate pointer behavior in python for integers.

What I ended up doing is wrapping an int in a class because the class can then be passed by reference

```
class MyInteger:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.i < other
    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.i <= other
....
```

I was wondering if this is a feasible option for getting a pointer-like behavior or if not, how should I go about this?

Comment: I can't picture what you're thinking.  ints in Python are already objects, just like any other object.  EVERYTHING is passed by reference.  Are you trying to make mutable int objects?

Comment: Why do you want "pointer-like behaviour" in the first place? What aspect of pointers are you trying to reproduce? What problem are you trying to solve? There's a very good chance this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: from what I know, python takes care of all the pointer behavior for you right? what is the issue with just assigning it to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Enter [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)

You should probably never do this but something like this is possible

```
import ctypes
x = 100
ctypes.cast(id(x), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))[6] = 10
print(x) # 10
print(99 + 1) # 10
```

Obviously this only works because python caches smaller integers.

I take no credit for figuring this out - original source [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2441cv/can_you_change_the_value_of_1/)